# cucumber-js gherkin: regular expression using custom parameterType

Tags: cucumberjs

As  user of [cucumber-js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/api_reference.md),

given a [custom parameter type](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/api_reference.md#defineparametertypename-preferforregexpmatch-regexp-transformer-useforsnippets) (eg below),

then I would like to have a feature whose step is defined by a regular expression, but references the custom parameter type.

Example custom parameter type:

```js
defineParameterType({
  name: "http-method",
  useForSnippets: true,
  regexp: /"(PUT|POST|GET|PATCH|DELETE)"/,
  transformer: method => method.toLowerCase(),
});
```

Am I asking too much, or is it possible? I can't find it documented, and can't imagine how it would be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

- The regex on the step definition needs to match the regex that you have defined on your `defineParameterType`.
- The parameter name on the function that implements your step needs to match the name of your `defineParameterType`

---

For example, the following steps

```js
Feature: api request

        Scenario: submit request
            Given I send a "PUT" request to my endpoint
              And I send a "POST" request to my endpoint
              And I send a "GET" request to my endpoint
              And I send a "PATCH" request to my endpoint
              And I send a "DELETE" request to my endpoint
```

...are implemented by the following step definition

```js
Given(/^I send a "(PUT|POST|GET|PATCH|DELETE)" request to my endpoint$/, async function (httpMethod) {
    console.log(httpMethod)
});
```

...and with the following `defineParameterType` (note that the regex declaration here is simpler than the one that you posted on your question)

```js
defineParameterType({
  name: "httpMethod",
  useForSnippets: true,
  regexp: /PUT|POST|GET|PATCH|DELETE/,
  transformer: method => method.toLowerCase(),
});
```

...I get the following output

```
Feature: api request

  Scenario: submit request
    Given I send a "PUT" request to my endpoint
put
    And I send a "POST" request to my endpoint
post
    And I send a "GET" request to my endpoint
get
    And I send a "PATCH" request to my endpoint
patch
    And I send a "DELETE" request to my endpoint
delete
```

Comment: Have you checked your solution?